# nginx+ uwsgi gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi, 502

I used [this guide](http://oqlid.blogspot.com/2011/06/django-deployment-on-ubuntu-1004-using.html) to set it up and it was working to server my django app for a while, but after adding a new django module, without touching any of the nginx or uwsgi configs, now the server leads to 502 502 Bad Gateway error. The nginx error.log  says:

> *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x,
>   server: blabla.com, request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:4000", host:
>   "x.x.x.x"

I appreciate your hints to resolve this.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever solved this problem. The same thing is happening to me now and its really frustrating.

Comment: @TheBeagle This happens due to the upstream script crashing before it can properly close the connection. Most likely it's a bad module that causes a segmentation fault or some form of crash.

Answer (score 3):

This error usually indicates that your Django application has crashed (raised an unhandled exception). You should be able to get more information from the uwsgi logs at `/var/log/uwsgi`.

Comment: Odd that it SEG faults on exception, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It doesn't segfault. It just raises an unhandled exception.

Comment: That's what I meant, the logs say its a seg fault but the reality is that it's an unhandled exception.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, I didn't remember that. I'm quite unsatisfied with uwsgi (too many features, very underdocumented) and I think I'll migrate to gunicorn or so one day.